# Cross compiling perl for Android ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lpthread

Tags: android, c++, perl

Good day,

I'm following this tutorial to cross compile perl for Android [Compiling Perl for Android](https://dev.to/jccr/compiling-perl-for-android-12a4)
Unfortunately I got stuck when running the Configure Script in the Perl directory:

```
Checking your choice of C compiler and flags for coherency...
```

I've tried to compile and run the following simple program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("Ok\n"); return(0); }
```

I used the command:

```
/home/janny/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android23-clang -o try -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-protector-strong try.c -lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -llog
/home/janny/perl-5.38.2/Cross/run-adb-shell ./try
```

and I got the following output:

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lpthread
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lcrypt
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lutil
clang-17: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I can't compile the test program.
You have a BIG problem.  Shall I abort Configure [y]  
Ok.  Stopping Configure.
```

I'm trying to compile it on ubuntu-22.04.4 and as a windows only user I'm a bit lost here.
I already tried installing the pthread lib using:

```
apt install libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

But the error persists.

Comment: Can you create a docker image with Ubuntu 22.04 for cross compilation? Then we can try to reproduce